# added Children but objects not displaying in Flash

Tags: flash, oop, actionscript

I'm adding a series of objects dynamically to my flash movie from xml but they won't appear when I run the movie. I have nearly identical code adding objects in a different swf that works just fine. I have tested this 8 ways from Sunday including ensuring that they were added to the container which is a child of the main MovieClip (tested the display list), that they were added to stage (had a listener for ADDED_TO_STAGE) and that their position was correct (displayed x,y values and compared them to mouseX & mouseY values). They are in the correct place in the display list. Still there are no objects. The class is linked correctly, I have movie clips in the library.

Any ideas what could be causing the problem?
I feel like I've checked everything.

'public class MiniMap extends MovieClip
    {

```
    private var expLoader:LoadXML = new LoadXML("Experiences.xml",true);
    public var expList:XMLList;
    private var popCont:Sprite = new Sprite();
    private var pop:PopUp;
    private var expCont:Sprite = new Sprite();
    private var pnt:Point;
    private var exp:Experiences;


    public function MiniMap()
    {
        // requires mouseup mousedown (pan) and close functions
        //must load experiences which will have their own class
        popCont.name = "popCont";
        expCont.name = "expCont";
        expCont.x = 0;
        expCont.y = 0;
        expCont.visible = true;
        expCont.width = 4000;
        expCont.height = 3000;
        mm.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, panMap, false, 0, true);
        expLoader.addEventListener("xmlLoaded", onLoadexp);
        mm.addChild(popCont);
        mm.addChildAt(expCont, 2);
    }
    private function onLoadexp(e:Event):void
    {



        expList = new XMLList(expLoader.xml.*);
        trace(expList.Longitude[1]);

        for (var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            exp = new Experiences(expList.Description[i],expList.Experience_Name[i]);
            exp.x = i * 0.5 + 1156;
            exp.y = i*0.75 + 1651;
            exp.name = expList.Experience_ID[i];

            /*exp.x = 1284.3216 * expList.Longitude[i] + 101472.0151;
            exp.y = -1744.6503 * expList.Latitude[i] + 80213.7461;*/

            exp.titl = expList.Experience_Name[i];
            exp.desc = expList.Description[i];

            exp.phourl = expList.photo[i];
            exp.type = expList.County[i];

            switch (exp.type)
            {
                case "City of Kawartha Lakes" :
                    exp.gotoAndPlay("Yellow");
                    break;
                case "Peterborough County" :
                    exp.gotoAndPlay("Green");
                    break;
                case "Northumberland County" :
                    exp.gotoAndPlay("Blue");
                    break;
                case "Northumberland" :
                    exp.gotoAndPlay("Red");
                    break;
            }
            exp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onExpClick, false,0, true);
            exp.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded, false,0, true);

            expCont.addChild(exp);

        }

        trace(expCont.root);

    }



    private function onExpClick(m:MouseEvent):void
    {

        //check for other popups 
        if (popCont.numChildren > 0)
        {
            closePop();
        }

        pop = new PopUp(m.target.titl,m.target.desc);
        pop.closer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closePop);
        mm.popCont.addChild(pop);


    }

    private function onAdded(e:Event):void
    {

        trace(e.target.name + " was added to the stage at "+e.target.x + ", " + e.target.y);


    }

    private function closePop():void {
        mm.popCont.removeChildAt(0);
    }

    private function panMap(m:MouseEvent):void
    {
        //click and drag to pan the minimap
        mm.startDrag();
        trace(mouseX+", "+mouseY);
        mm.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, relsMap, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function relsMap(m:MouseEvent):void
    {
        //drops the minimap
        mm.stopDrag();

    }'
```

Comment: Welcome to Programmers! This site is for more subjective questions, but hordes of experts at StackOverflow will be happy to help you. I expect this question will be migrated there shortly.

Comment: What class does Experiences extend?

Answer (score 2):

Have you used the `addchild()` command once the object have been loaded to flash? You need to add objects to the display list for them to show on the stage (Assuming you are coding in AS3)

http://forums.creativecow.net/thread/190/864240

Comment: Yes. I used container.addChild() and then used a trace statement to list all the children of the stage. It showed that the children were all there in their proper container but they were not visible as objects in the swf.

Comment: And you used the addChild() for the container? `container.addChild(child)` and then `addChild(Container)`

Comment: Yes. They all appear in the display list.

Comment: Do you think it could be something screwey with the coordinate system? Or could it be something to do with the object in the library?

Comment: My AS3 is kind of rusty, that's one of the point that I remembered when i switched from as2 to as3

Answer (score 1):

Looks like here is your problem

```
exp.x = i * 0.5 + 1156;
exp.y = i*0.75 + 1651;
```

I don't know what size your swf is but I doubt it can handle these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, theres not much to do on this end unless you post some code.

I will say this: If I'm in a situation where something aught to be happening, and isn't, you just have to, very methodically, trace your way back through the logic chain. If your objects aren't showing up on the stage, there is a distinctly limited number of things that could be out of sorts.
A short (and incomplete) checklist:

**XML** - is data being retrieved and parsed correctly? trace out the vars.
**Library** - if you are relying on objects in the library, ensure their linkage names are all correct, and your pathing is correct.
**Display list** - obviously, addChild is essential, but what is your display list order? is there something obscuring your objects? 
**Object props** - finally, make sure properties like "scale", "visibility" etc... are all set properly.

And failing all that, take your sequence out of the project, and test the logic with a minimum number of variables. If you test case is working fine, then change the scope of bug hunt...

good luck

Comment: Thanks for the checklist. That helps. Everything checks out. I'm going to try that last suggestion. Part of the issue could be that this swf is at the max stage size which seems to mess with the coordinate system and the main MC is larger still than the stage.